# I can't scroll my page

Tags: python, listview, kivy

How to add my widget in a `ScrollView` or `ListView` to scroll it?

I've written a code but it doesn't work good, this is my **main.py**:

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.lang import Builder 

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.uix.scrollview  import ScrollView  

from random import random

class chat_history(BoxLayout):
 def profile(self):
  return random(),random(),random()


Builder.load_file('widg.kv')

class myApp(App ):
 def build(self):
  x=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
  s=ScrollView()
  for i in range(1,21):
   x.add_widget(chat_history(height=50))
  s.add_widget(x)
  return s

myApp().run()
```

And this is my **kv file**:

```
<chat_history>:
height:100
BoxLayout:
    height:50
    name:'haha very funny '
    size_hint_y:None
    id:cv
    orientation:'horizontal'
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb:root.profile()
        Ellipse:
            pos:root.pos
    Label:
        text_hint:{'x':0,'y':0.1}
        pos:root.pos 
        size_hint_x:0.7
        height:cv.height 
        text:cv.name
        id:lbl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should prevent the layout from automatically adapting its height to the height of its parent widget (`size_hint_y = None`).

On the other hand, make sure the height is such that there is something to scroll. You must explicitly specify layout height.

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.uix.scrollview  import ScrollView  
from random import random


kv_text = '''
<chat_history>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height:100
    BoxLayout:
        height:50
        name:'haha very funny '
        size_hint_y:None
        id:cv
        orientation:'horizontal'
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb:root.profile()
            Ellipse:
                pos:root.pos
        Label:
            text_hint:{'x':0,'y':0.1}
            pos:root.pos 
            size_hint_x:0.7
            height:cv.height 
            text:cv.name
            id:lbl
'''

class chat_history(BoxLayout):
    def profile(self):
        return random(),random(),random()

class myApp(App ):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv_text)
        x=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical',  size_hint_y=None)  #<<<<<<<<<<<
        x.bind(minimum_height=x.setter('height'))               #<<<<<<<<<<<
        s=ScrollView()
        for i in range(1,21):
            x.add_widget(chat_history(height=50))
        s.add_widget(x)
        return s

myApp().run()
```